# How to parse string to int?

Tags: java, android, parser-generator

my string is 743.4445 and I want it to show 743 so it has to parse to double and then parse to int so I try like this

```
(int)(Double.valueOf(743.4445);
```

(actually 743.4445 is from server thus I don't know exactly value)

what am I suppose to do?

Comment: spend a little time researching it yourself, it is faster than writing up a question here.

Comment: why isn't it working? it looks right (albeit with a missing closing brace) are you getting any errors? can you post the error?

Answer (score 3):

why not google "java get whole number"

```
double d = Double.valueOf(s.trim()).doubleValue();
```

Heck, for that matter why not use IndexOf on the string looking for the .?  :)

Comment: looking for "." works bad for locales where "," is used as separator (like "ru")

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

Store this value in one string and try this.

String number = "743.4445";

```
(int)Double.parseDouble(number)
```

Comment: @ chirag : 2nd option is more appropriate, as one should not use hard coded values as these can change

Comment: @Stuti, I suspect that was the intention and the code was only there as a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`NumberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(boolean value)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setParseIntegerOnly%28boolean%29) method?

Example:

```
String s = "743.5555";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
format.setParseIntegerOnly (true);
int value = format.parse(s).intValue();
```